# Use Google API only after user stop typing

Tags: javascript

```js
var locInputTimeout = null;
var input = document.getElementById('inputTxt');

input.onkeyup = function(e){
  clearTimeout(locInputTimeout);
  locInputTimeout = setTimeout(function(){initAutocomplete()},2000);
};
  

function initAutocomplete() {
 var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({'country': ['my']});
  alert("I am here!");
}

'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<MY API KEY HERE>&libraries=places',
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputTxt" />
```

The above code is working with api key filled.

I am expecting every time user stop typing for 2 seconds, it will call google api for location suggestion. However, it happened as below. Any help is highly appreciated! ;)

**Expecting:**

1. I type "KLIA" - textbox:"KLIA"
2. I stop typing for 2 seconds
3. Pop up "I am here" and location suggestion is showing
4. I type "2" - textbox: "KLIA2"
5. I stop typing for 2 seconds
6. Pop up "I am here" and location suggestion is showing

**Scenario:**

1. I type "KLIA" - textbox:"KLIA"
2. I stop typing for 2 seconds
3. Pop up "I am here" but location suggestion NOT showing
4. I type "2" - textbox: "KLIA2"
5. Location suggestion immediately showing
6. Pop up "I am here" after 2 seconds

Comment: easiest way to do this is by using "debounce" or "throttle", look up those concepts :-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that what you want to achieve is to delay the prediction of places in the google search input by two seconds.
as stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41005896/4043487) , there is currently no way of doing that.

In what regards to your approach, what your script actually does, is to atach an 'autoCompleter' to your input two seconds after an event is fired, and as you can see in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OsvaldoM/ekvx1kba/17/), the autocomplete will only be fired when the value of your input changes, but it does not know when it is attached to an element that already has a value, and that's why in step3 although the alert is shown, the form is not autocompleted

I did try to manually trigger a `keyup` event in this other[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OsvaldoM/4y2ynqds/1/) with the following script:

```
locInputTimeout = setTimeout(function(){initAutocomplete()},2000);

function initAutocomplete() {
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    var currentValue=input.value
    autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({'country': ['my']});
    input.value='';
    input.value=currentValue;
    input.focus();
}
```

however, for some reason I can't get it to work. hopefully, you can continue from there.
My suggestion, is that you rely on gmaps internal mechanism for determining when to re-run the autocomplete, since they probably used better heuristics to do it and also according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35501648/4043487) , setting the initial value for the autocomplete is no ordinary task.

Comment: Thank you for the answers and fiddles you refer. I will definitely give it a try asap and come back to you if I successfully did ;)